# getting error in WordPress ,not able to run my JS file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have custom code in WordPress (Elementor) which carry custom jquery, when I run that page it give me error and not letting me run that code

Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “//domainname.com/js/validate.js”. my-score:1386:30

The resource from “//domainname.com/js/jquery.countTo.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

How can I let WordPress let this run? or any solution?

Comment: example please?

Comment: See if the path is correct. You may be getting a 404 page, which would explain the mime type being returned as text/html instead of text/js.